# Взять url из большой строки

Tags: javascript, python, регулярные-выражения, selenium, selenium-webdriver

У меня есть программа, которая получаем содержимое HTML атрибута:

```
code = driver.execute_script('return document.getElementById("message-body").getAttribute("srcdoc")')
```

Вот результат переменной `code`:

`Здравствуйте!`

`Для завершения регистрации пройдите по ссылке:`

`https://123456.ru/123456/activate?token=случайные_символы`

`С уважением, Администрация ??????`

Мне нужно получить только ссылку `https://123456.ru/123456/activate?token=случайные_символы`

Реализовать можно как на Python, так и на JS

Comment: с чем возникли проблемы?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Возможный вариант на JS:

```js
const code = `
Здравствуйте!

Для завершения регистрации пройдите по ссылке: 

https://123456.ru/123456/activate?token=случайные_символы

С уважением, Администрация ?????? 
`;

const [url] = code.match(/https:\S+/);

console.log(url);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
code = driver.execute_script('return document.getElementById("message- 
body").getAttribute("srcdoc")')
res = [url for url in code.split('\n') if url.find('http') != -1]
print(res)

#ответ
#['https://123456.ru/123456/activate?token=случайные_символы']
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]